# TextRank Run time

Tags: java, graph, nlp, jgrapht, opennlp

I implemented textrank in java but it seems pretty slow. Does anyone know about its expected performance?

**If it's not expected to be slow**, could any of the following be the problem:

1) It didn't seem like there was a way to create an edge and add a weight to it at the same in JGraphT time so I calculate the weight and if it's > 0, I add an edge. I later recalculate the weights to add them while looping through the edges. Is that a terrible idea?

2) I'm using JGraphT. Is that a slow library?

3) Anything else I could do to make it faster?

Comment: Please quantify "pretty slow".

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by "pretty slow".  A bit of googling found this paragraph:

> *"We calculated the total time for RAKE and TextRank (as an average over 100iterations) to extract keywords from the Inspec testing set of 500 abstracts, afterthe abstracts were read from ﬁles and loaded in memory. RAKE extracted key-words from the 500 abstracts in 160 milliseconds. TextRank extracted keywordsin 1002 milliseconds, over 6 times the time of RAKE."*

(See http://www.scribd.com/doc/51398390/11/Evaluating-ef%EF%AC%81ciency for the context.)

So from this, I infer that a decent TextRank implementation should be capable of extracting keywords from ~500 abstracts in ~1second.